# Do KVM switches work with 144Hz Gsync gaming monitors?

Tags: usb, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a monitor that does 144Hz and Gsync at 2560x1440. It only uses displayport to support these features. Assuming I get a KVM that works with DisplayPort, if I use the KVM with this monitor, will my desktop still be able to use 144Hz and Gsync on this monitor through the KVM? Or does this depend on the KVM?

Comment: You should be able to get 2560x1440@144Hz if the KVM natively supports DisplayPort input and output. Still, read the spec of the KVM before buying it. I doubt very much that you can still get GSync though (the nvidia card/driver needs to be able to talk to the GSync module on the monitor directly to adjust the refresh rate dynamically).

Comment: So KVM switches do _not_ act as direct electrical connections?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm the IOGear GCS62DP and Tripp Lite B004-DP2UA2-K (they are essentialy the same unit underneath) both work for Gsync at 100 hz on my x34. It's displayport 1.2, which is essential for Gsync to work at those resolutions.

Drawback is, the unit essentially disconnects the display from the non-active computer, just as if you had unplugged the cable. So in essense, it actually IS acting as a switched electrical connection.

For me the trade-off is worth it to have 2 computers hit 100hz, instead of 1 at 100hz and the other at 50hz over hdmi.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! disconnecting from the non-active computer is actually what I'm looking for, because I want to use it with a USB dock as one of the "computers"

Comment: A few months ago, I have purchased the same dock you mentioned and I can confirm that it definitely works!